# How to integrate WSO2 with GitHub?

Tags: github, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to integrate WSO2 with GitHub so, that i can push the code directly to  my repository.
Is there any configuration file in wso2am that serves this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have a look at GitHub Conenctor which is for wso2 EI https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Github+Connector